# How to ensure there is no vertical gap when two columns are unequal heights in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have a bootstrap problem

Imagine I have the following layout

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 classA">Some contents A</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 classB">Some contents B</div>
<div class="clearfix col-xs-12 col-lg-8 classC>Some contents C</div>
```

Now if the contents of B are larger in height than contents of A, then there is a vertical gap between in between A and C similar to below. I do not want that gap. Yes, I can use margin-top and all those sort of things. However, I wonder if there is a better option - maybe with flex or bootstrap or layout wise etc?

[image]

Comment: If you want a quick solution you can use masonry plugin or jump to Bootstrap 4 and use flexbox for that.

Comment: It's called `masonry` and there are so many questions about it that it actually has its own [tag on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masonry). You might also want to look into [CSS columns](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/). @makshh as a matter of fact, you can't really get masonry with `flexbox`. The closest would be to stretch the items into having equal heights/widths on a row/column (depending on `flex-direction`).

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing out, I thought it is like 3 lines of flexbox code :)

Comment: No masonary is not something I am looking to use for this.. In terms of flexbox, is it possible to have something done with bootstrap 3?

Comment: I found something like this http://codepen.io/manabox/pen/YXbpZZ If you search for `flexbox masonry` on Codepen you will get a lot of examples.

Comment: Bootstrap 3 and `flexbox` are not incompatible, Hello. Define *"something"*, please.

Comment: You're correct, @makshh. It can be done with `flex-direction:column` and it's flexbox. But you need to set a `max-height` for the container or it won't work. But look what happens when you don't know how much content you have (and you don't know what `max-height` to set. It's same pen, with more items: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKYpKg

Comment: Yeah I see, what about this? https://jsbin.com/loronibali/2/edit?output

Comment: `-webkit-column-count: 3; -moz-column-count: 3; column-count: 3;` :) Considering it's only CSS, it's pretty awesome.

Comment: Any solution for this topic? I am using bs 3 and i am facing the same problem